# Shut down C# dll in AutoCAD

Tags: c#, forms, dll, exit

I have written a C# plugin for AutoCAD, which is just a dll with some forms and user inputs and so on.
Is it possible to close only the dll?

I tried:

```
 Application.Exit();
```

but this does close the whole AutoCAD application, thats not what I want.

It also does not help closing a form because I have multiple forms which are not globally accessable.

I just want to add some code to demonstrate where I could possibly want to close my plugin:

```
// first class

            [CommandMethod("PluginName"]
            public static void StartPlugin()
            {
                 LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow();
                 DialogResult loginResult= login.ShowDialog();

                 if (loginResult== DialogResult.OK)
                 {
                    StartInventoryPropertiesSelection();
                 }
            }


// second class


    public partial class LoginWindow : Form
    {

        public LoginWindow()
        {
               InitializeComponent();

                // Cancel here
                Plugin.Quit // ==> this is what I am looking for
        }

    }
```

Comment: try [`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately this also closes AutoCAD

Comment: does plugin has property named quit?  in anyway show how you start to run plugin

Comment: In AutoCAD you just define a function as entry point for the plugin:
[CommandMethod("PluginCommand")]
public static void StartPlugin()
{
}
The rest is proper C# code. So I am not shure where there could be a quit method or property

Comment: so update your question show all code it will be more helpful,so show that rest proper c# code

Comment: sorry but my plugin is huge (maybe 50.000 loc)
I just want to be able to close the plugin everywhere
But I will update my code to just show you an example

Comment: The notion of "closing" a DLL just doesn't exist.  The closest possible match is "unloading".  Which is not in the cards either, you are subject to the way AutoCAD loads plugins and it doesn't support unloading them.  You can tinker with creating your own AppDomain and loading a chunk of code into it but there's little joy in that as long as there's no obvious goal.